# Spring cannot find implementation to interface

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to Spring and am trying to use it to dependency inject DAOs in my project.

I have an interface:

> MyDao.java

```
package path.to.my.dao;
// my imports

public interface MyDao extends BasicDao<MyType> {

  // my query signatures

}
```

> MyDaoImpl.java

```
package path.to.my.dao.impl;
// my imports

public class MyDaoImpl extends BasicDao<MyType> implements MyDao {

  // my query implementations
}
```

So I now have a plugin that uses `MyDao`, so I have the following:

> MyPlugin.java

```
package path.to.my.plugin;
// ...
@Autowired
private MyDao myDAO;
// ...
```

In my xml file, I have the following:

```
<bean id="MyDao" class="path.to.my.dao.impl.MyDaoImpl">
  <!-- assume emf is OK: entity manager factory provided by spring -->
  <property="emf" value="emFactory" /> 
</bean>

...

<bean id="myPlugin" class="path.to.my.plugin.MyPlugin">
  <property="myDAO" value="MyDao" />
</bean>
```

When I try to run, I get the following error:

> Cannot find class [path.to.my.dao.impl.MyDaoImpl] for bean with name 'MyDao' defined in ServletContextResource ...

Why can't spring find the implementation for my interface `MyDao`? This pattern is used through my project, but it doesn't seem to work for the injection I'm attempting to perform.

Comment: Seems like the class isn't on the classpath.

Comment: Shouldnt there be a @Repository annotation on MyDaoImpl ???

Comment: @WeareBorg Only if they were component scanning.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming `MyDaoImpl` exist at `path.to.my.dao.impl.MyDaoImpl`, there are 2 ways to solve the problem:

**First,**
modify `myPlugin` bean in your configuration file as below:

```
  <bean id="myPlugin" class="package.to.my.plugin.MyPlugin">
    </bean>
```

**Secondly**, remove `@Autowired` from `MyPlugin` class and create setter and getter for the property `myDAO` as below:

```
package path.to.my.plugin;
// ...

private MyDao myDAO;

//setter and getter for myDAO
// ...
```

Also, modify `myPlugin` bean in your configuration file as below:

```
...

<bean id="myPlugin" class="package.to.my.plugin.MyPlugin">
 <property name="myDAO" >
            <ref bean="MyDao"/>
        </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Are these mutually exclusive solutions? It doesn't seem like it.

Comment: These are not mutually exclusive solutions.